# Trouble Calling Helper Method Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

Working in Rails 3.2 Ruby 1.9.  
Trying to figure how to call a helper method that doesn't rely on a model object. For example my app has a Products model when I write a helper method like this:

```
 module StoreHelper
def units_available (product)
  sales = product.line_items.total_product_sale.sum("quantity")
  units_available = (product.total_avail - sales)
end
```

I can call it in my view with no problems like this

```
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
<%=units_available(product)%> 
<%end%>
```

However when I have a helpers like these:

```
 module StoreHelper
 def current_promo_status (level1_status, level2_status)
   if level1_status == "Active"
   current_status = "1"
   elsif level2_status == "Active"
   current_status = "2"
   else current_status = "3"
 end
end

def discount (current_promo_status)
  discount = product.price3 if current_promo_status == 3 
  discount = product.price2 if current_promo_status == 2 
  discount = product.price if current_promo_status == 1 
end
```

I cant figure out how to call the discount method to my view. I have tried the following in the view:

```
<%=discount(current_promo_status)%>
```

and

```
<%=products.discount(current_promo_status)%>
```

I have also  tried moving the methods to my controller like so:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
 include StoreHelper
 def discount (current_promo_status)
  @discount = product.price3 if current_promo_status == 3 
  @discount = product.price2 if current_promo_status == 2 
  @discount = product.price if current_promo_status == 1 
 end
```

and then calling it in the view via

```
<%=@discount%>
```

What’s the right way to go about doing this? I’m fairly certain it's something simple as I’m very new to programming.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: when i move it to the controller i dont get any errors the value just shows up blank. when i try the <%=discount(current_promo_status)%>  and <%=products.discount(current_promo_status)%>  i get syntax errors.

Comment: Unfortunately `syntax errors` is not very descriptive.  Any time you have errors and have a question about it, the best thing you can do to get help is to copy and paste the actual error along with your question.

Comment: What is the type of passed `current_promo_status` ? Are you sure it's integer? Or string `"1"`? If so, the helper returns `nil` and nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What’s the right way to go about doing this?"

Put your methods either in a helper file or in the model itself.  If the methods are shared across multiple models, extract them out into modules.

It's important to note that there is no link between the variable `current_promo_status` in the view layer and your method `current_promo_status()` in the module.  So in the view layer, the `current_promo_status` variable would need to already be defined (e.g. `current_promo_status = 3`) in order to call the `discount` method there.

`products.discount()` doesn't really make sense, as `products` is likely not even defined, and if it was, it would be an Array class, which doesn't have the `discount` method defined.

The `@` sign is used to share variables between the controller (where you should define the values for your variables) and the view (where you should display those values).

So without knowing your specifics, a standard layout would look something like:

### products_controller.rb

```
...
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

### views/products/index.html.erb

```
...
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% promo_status = product.current_promo_status(product.level1_status, product.level2_status) %>
  <% discount = product.discount(promo_status) %>
  # display discount as needed
  ...
<% end %>
...
```

And usually when you need to do operations like this in the view layer, you'll pull the methods into the model (or module) to simplify everything so that all you would have to do is something like `product.discount_for_display` in the view layer.  This is called `refactoring`.